# How to set inputted value in widget-less class in Flutter

Tags: flutter, widget

Is there any way to set a inputted value in a widget less class in flutter ? I have a class containing all configuration but there is no widget in that class. Now I want to take input from use and want to set that value in config class.

I tried, it says `The return type 'AllConfig' isn't a 'Widget', as required by the closure's context.dart (return_of_invalid_type_from_closure)`

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In the widget-less class you can create a function which has a input value

```
class TestClass {

static testValue;

_functionInClass(inputValue){
   print(inputValue);
   setState(() {
      testValue= inputValue;
   });
}
```

Then from elsewhere you can import that class and call the function

```
import '.../testClassesFile.dart' as testClass;

var x = 1;
testClass._functionInClass(x); //call function in another class with a value
```

Comment: Hi @August Kimo, I have tried your code. First part working fine for me. When I implement second part it showing " class TestClass


The class 'TestClass' can't be used as a mixin because it declares a constructor.dart(mixin_class_declares_constructor) "